# Appropriate use case for "accepted"?

Tags: rest, http

We have a task enqueued by a REST endpoint that will create a resource and then enqueue a task either immediately or delayed based on some business logic.

I was thinking of using `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` for the immediate case, and `HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted` for the case where that task has been delayed, however, the resource POSTed  is created immediately, it's just the resulting task that affects the user which is delayed, so it seems like a bit of misuse to do a `202`. Am I overthinking this? Is there a better way I can tell the client about this delayed task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 202 Accepted

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

Seems like a good fit to me.  That the resource gets created immediately does not actually complete the processing in your case.

Answer (score 4):

There are two similar responses that should be considered depending on what the expected response should be.

The 202 Accepted response is a "yep, got that" response. The resource is created and the server will get around to doing something with that.

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html )

The other response to look at is the 201 Created response:

> The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created. The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field. The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. The origin server MUST create the resource before returning the 201 status code. If the action cannot be carried out immediately, the server SHOULD respond with 202 (Accepted) response instead.

( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html )

In particular, the 201 response responds back with the resource location that has been created.  This part matches the description of your requirement:

> ... the resource POSTed is created immediately, it's just the resulting task that affects the user which is delayed ...

Related blog post:

- [http status 201 created vs 202 accepted](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/04/http-status-201-created-vs-202-accepted/)

Answer (score 0):

There is the question whether 202 is the right result for what you are doing, and the other question is how the client processes it.

If a client receives a 202, chances are that it doesn't handle it properly (many clients will only recognise 200 as success, everything else is bad).

But what if the client recognises it: 202 means the server promised to do it, but the operation might actually fail. That means the client can't rely on the server having stored the data. The client must make some other request at some later point to check whether the request actually has been performed. That's a pain.

So unless you have a lengthy queue of operations that you need to do, where you suspect a client could timeout (60 seconds usually), I'd think very hard if it isn't better to return 200 when the request has actually been processed.